# Javascript Multi style set

Tags: javascript, css, styles

```
<div id="newsinsite" >gasdgasdgf</div>
<div id="newsinsite" >hasdgfasd</div>
<div id="newsinsite" >gasdgasd</div>
<div id="newsinsite" >gasdgasd</div>


<script>
    document.getElementById('style').style.width = "430px";
</script>
```

Javascript is give a set style for all div with newsinsite. Please help me :)

Comment: `getElementById('newsinsite')` maybe?

Comment: IDs must be unique. Use class instead.

Comment: There are so many things wrong here that you just should start over with a book.

Comment: `id` should be unique, you are looking for a `class`

Comment: <div id="newsinsite" >gasdgasdgf</div>
<div id="newsinsite" >hasdgfasd</div>
<div id="newsinsite" >gasdgasd</div>
<div id="newsinsite" >gasdgasd</div>


<script>
    document.getElementById('newsinsite').style.width = "430px";
</script>

Comment: not working, I copied a bad line

Comment: don't post code in the comments (unless it's a tiny piece of code). Update your original question instead

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
<div id="newsinsite1" class="newsinsite">gasdgasdgf</div>
<div id="newsinsite2" class="newsinsite">gasdgasdgf</div>
<div id="newsinsite3" class="newsinsite">gasdgasdgf</div>
<div id="newsinsite4" class="newsinsite">gasdgasdgf</div>


<script>
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("newsinsite");
    for (var i=0;i<elem.length;i++) {
        elem[i].style.width = "430px";
    }
</script>
```

But if this is a static setting use css instead:

```
<style>
    .newsinsite {
        width: "430px";
    }
</style>
```

UPDATE

For IE8 support, use `querySelectorAll('.classname')` instead of `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: be aware that old IE versions won't work with getElementByClassName

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="newsinsite">gasdgasdgf</div>
<div class="newsinsite">hasdgfasd</div>
<div class="newsinsite">gasdgasd</div>
<div class="newsinsite">gasdgasd</div>


<script>
    var i = 0, els = document.getElementsByClassName('newsinsite'), len = els.length;

    for(;i<len;i++) {
        els[i].style.width = '430px';
    }
</script>
```

Or, set it with CSS:

```
.newsinsite { 
    width: 430px;
}
```